# Why does orient Path = true cause the sprite node to rotate CW when the path is horizontal?

Tags: uibezierpath

**Why does orient Path = true cause the sprite node to rotate CW when the path is horizontal?**

**== BEGIN Edit ==**

**(1)** Someone suggested I need to create a `Pivot Point`. However, based on my research, a `Pivot Point` exists for a `SCNode`, **not** a `SKSpriteNode`.

**(2)** No luck even when I changed the `anchorPoint` to various `x,y` combinations. Problem did not go away no matter what combination I chose. It's currently set to `0.5,0.5`. I am definitely ready to cry "Uncle" on this challenge.

**(3)** So, allow me to continue ...

**== END Edit ==**

Here's just one example of my challenge:

```
    let trainAction = SKAction.follow(
                                  trainPath.cgPath,
                                  asOffset: false,
                                  orientToPath: true,
                                  duration: 0.1)
    myTrain.run(trainAction.reversed())
```

I have `myTrain.zRotation = 0.0`

`myTrain` is a simple locomotive,`trainPath` = the railroad tracks

Docs state with `orientToPath: true`, that the Node will always orient itself such that it's **facing** the `UIBezierPath`.

To me, **facing** means that the wheels of the locomotive are **facing** the BezierPath (= `trainPath`)

Apparently I am wrong in this interpretation ... if so, what is the correct interpretation?

FYI, here is a snapshot of my initial placement of the locomotive on the tracks using `.position`:

[image]

... and here is what happens when I start moving the locomotive:

[image]

These snapshots indicate that **facing** means that the nose of the locomotive is **facing** the BezierPath (= `trainPath`).

If true, how do I eliminate that CW rotation?

I have even tried rotating `myTrain` CCW 90 degrees **before** the `.follow` = same exact result.

I have drawn what I am looking for - hopefully it helps to diagnose my problem:

[image]